# match pixel size of element on iOS screen with CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to create a notification container with CSS that is the same size as notifications on iOS on my iPhone 6S.

I have created screen grabs of portrait and landscape. When I view the images the sizes of the notifications in pixels are 718x262 and 841x262 respectively.

When I create the notifications with the same height (262px) they are displayed on the device differently 200px in portrait and 357px in landscape).

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bmkv2gua62r4zly/AAC0xPZIURWZFwCb9pFzDk1Da?dl=0

Comment: Don't iPhone6s have x2 retina? Try doubling your dimensions.

Comment: Yes it's 2x density but that's not the issue exactly. Setting my element to 262px in height already displays it at 357px in landscape, so it's already too big.

Comment: Half them then, maybe?

Comment: But in portrait the height is 200px

Comment: Are you using media queries? In media queries the dimensions for landscape and portrait are the same, they don't alternate in width and depth.

Comment: Only to change the horizontal position. I don't change the dimensions with media queries

Comment: http://appifiny.co.uk/demo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding viewport meta tags fixed the issue

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
```